# Sort tuples by averages of second element

Tags: sorting, csv, python-3.x

I have been able to convert a csv file to list format using a function. In doing so I was able to assign a name to a class number and thereafter 3 additional numbers e.g:

In the csv file:

```
Hussain     1   7   8   0
Alexandra   1   0   0   2
```

Became :

```
['Alexandra', 2],['Hussain', 8]
```

As the sorting method asked for the name in alphabetical order and the person's highest score. I used tuples to complete the code above and would like to carry on using tuples. 
Now I wish to be able to sort this so that it becomes highest averages to lowest, e.g, the sorting method for averages would result in:

```
[Hussain, 1.66666666667],[Alexandra, 0.6666666666]
```

These numbers are what I expect as they are the averages of the last three numbers in the csv file as the 2nd column is being ignored here. As Hussain has the highest average he is placed first. I would appreciate any possible help.

What I would like to be done is the following:

I would like to be able to print out all the students in order of highest averages to lowest. As Hussain has a higher average of 1.6, he is printed out first then Alexandra is printed as she has a lower average. These two students are from the same class (shown in the second column of the csv file) and they are to be printed when the user chooses class 1 to be sorted.

TIA

Comment: what are you want? only need sorting for highest averages to lowest? Need Input and Output sample which you want

Comment: Yes that's right, I want to sort the classes the the user chooses. The class chosen will need to be sorted from the highest averages to the lowest. A sample would be Hussain and Alexandra from class 1. So when the user chooses class 1, it will be sorted  from the highest to lowest averages in that class only. Hope that made more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have a list of class 1 like:

```
class1 = [['Alexandra', 1, 0, 0, 2], ['Hussain', 1, 7, 8, 0]]
```

then you sorted this according second element in lists of list

```
##this is class number 1 and you find class 1 people in second index of list by i[1] == 1(class number)
avg_list = [[i[0], float(sum(i[2:]))/len(i[2:])] for i in class1 if i[1] == 1 ]
dd = sorted(avg_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
dd.reverse()
print dd
```

Output:

```
[['Hussain', 5.0], ['Alexandra', 0.6666666666666666]]
```

Comment: The thing is I need to make the averages first from the tuples that I have. The tuple for both students looks something like this: [Hussain, 1, 7, 8, 0],[Alexandra, 1, 0, 0, 2] But I need the last three values to make the average then sort it from highest to lowest averages.

Comment: what r u want to show in output? this type [Hussain, 1, 7, 8, 0],[Alexandra, 1, 0, 0, 2] or this type ['Hussain', 1.66666666667], ['Alexandra', 0.6666666666

Comment: I want the output to be ['Hussain', 1.66666666667], ['Alexandra', 0.6666666666], Ill try the code above and report to you the outcome

Comment: Basically, there is more to the names used, Hussain and Alexandra are in class 1 but there are other people in class 2 and class 3. The user will choose one of these classes. The class chosen will then need to be sorted in order from the highest average to the lowest. The output should be like the ['Hussain', 1.66666666667], ['Alexandra', 0.6666666666] example.

Comment: Hussain avg 1.6 . how? my avg come 5.0

Comment: Oh because I do not want the first number after the name. That number is the class that the student is from, I need to make the averages from the LAST 3 numbers only.

Comment: Check answer. Is it okkk?

Answer (score 0):

Use key function in python's sort function. Read about it here:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html